# how to fill a mysql database from a data entries of a form?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I try to fill a data-base when a person create an account.My server is in node.js.
app.js:

```
var http=require("http");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;



// routes
var route = require('./route');
// model
var Model = require('./model');




app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(session({secret: 'secret strategic xxzzz code',
        resave:false,
        saveUninitialized:false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());




server.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("server listen at localhost:3000");});   
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
   new Model.User({username: username}).fetch().then(function(data) {
      var user = data;
      if(user === null) {
         return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid username or password'});
      } else {
         user = data.toJSON();
         if(!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid username or password'});
         } else {
            return done(null, user);



         }
      }
   });
}));



 passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user.username);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(username, done) {
       new Model.User({username: username}).fetch().then(function(user) {
          done(null, user);
       });
    });

    // signup
    // GET
    app.get('/signup', route.signUp);
    // POST
    app.post('/signup', route.signUpPost);
```

route.js:

```
var signUpPost = function(req, res, next) {
   var user = req.body;
   var usernamePromise = null;
   usernamePromise = new Model.User({username: user.username}).fetch();//verify the existence of username on the database


   return usernamePromise.then(function(model) {
      if(model) {
         res.render('index1', {title: 'Index', errorMessage: 'username already exists'});//verify if the entered username exists in the databas.
      } else {
         var password = user.password;
    var email=user.email;

    if(password.length<5){
        res.render('index1',{title:'index',errorMessage:'password so weak'});//password must been > 5 caracters.
    }
    else if(verifMail(email) === false){
        res.render('index1',{title:'index',errorMessage:'email invalid'});//if the email is not valid,it show an error
    }

    else{
         var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password);//crypt the password

         var signUpUser = new Model.User({username: user.username, password:hash,email:user.email,firstname:user.firstname,lastname:user.lastname});//add a new row in the database

         signUpUser.save().then(function(model) {
            signInPost(req, res, next);
         });
    };  
      }
   });
};
```

Model.js:

```
    var DB = require('./db').DB;

var User = DB.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'newuser',
   idAttribute: 'userId',
});

module.exports = {
   User: User
};
```

db.js:

```
 var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf');

var config = {
   host: 'localhost',  
   user: 'root', 
   password: '', 
   database: 'Users',
   charset: 'UTF8_GENERAL_CI'
};

var DB = Bookshelf.initialize({
   client: 'mysql', 
   connection: config
});

module.exports.DB = DB;
```

When a person click a button to signup,a modal display to enter his firstname,lastname,email and password.

```
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade"   role="dialog" >

            <div class="model-content">
              <div class="modal-header" >
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <!-- form -->
                <form id="register-form" role="form" method="post" action="/signup">


         <div class="form-group">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="User name">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="First name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">

                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">

                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
              </div>

              <div class="emaillogin">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default email-signin-button">
                  Submit
                </button>
              </div>

            </form>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default email-signin-button" data-dismiss="modal">
                  Close
                </button>

              </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

The page still reload for a long time and the data did not been saved in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your signUpPost function should return a view or redirect to another route but it returns a promise instead.

Besides a then() function should always return a promise or a value but it returns nothing. And you should always add a catch block;

I think you misunderstood the way Promises work.

```js
//...
usernamePromise.then(function(model) {
  if ( model ) throw new Error('username already exists');
  else {
    //...
    if( ...) { throw new Error('password so weak'); }
    else if( ...) { throw new Error('email invalid'); }
    else {
      //...
      return signUpUser.save();
    }
  }
}).then(function(model){
  // do what you want with model and redirect
  return res.redirect('/my/new/route'); 
}).catch(function(err){
  // do what you want with err (eg: use flash or console.log(err)) and redirect
  return res.redirect('/my/new/route'); 
});
//...
```